# Lightning Data Table Base Component Winter 18' - navigate to Sobject action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-base-component

How do you set an action on a column to Navigate to Sobject record?

Or when the name of the record is clicked fire an action.

Doesn't appear you can do it with the base component.

```
<lightning:card title="Entities">
    <lightning:datatable data="{!v.Contact}" 
        columns="{!v.mycolumns}" 
        keyField="Id"
        />

({
init : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set('v.mycolumns', [
        {label: 'ID', fieldName: 'Id', type: 'Id'},
        {label: 'Full Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'First Name', fieldName: 'FirstName', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'Last Name', fieldName: 'LastName', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'Phone, Primary', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone'},
        {label: 'Phone, Secondary', fieldName: 'Phone_Secondary__c', type: 'phone'},
        {label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'Email'},
        {label: 'Business Fax', fieldName: 'Fax', type: 'phone'},
        {label: 'Street', fieldName: 'MailingStreet', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'City', fieldName: 'MailingCity', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'State', fieldName: 'MailingState', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'Zip', fieldName: 'MailingPostalCode', type: 'number'},
    ]);
    helper.getData(component);
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now - this is not possible.

I asked the same question, and got an answer that it will be supported in the next release - see my question and the answers to it Here:

[Winter 18  problems](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193276/winter-18-lightningdatatable-problems)

Answer (score 0):

On your datatable you add a listener to row selection:

```
onrowselection="{! c.navigateToSObject }"/>
```

Then handle the event and redirect to the object.

```
navigateToSObject: function (cmp, event) {
    var selectedRows = event.getParam('selectedRows');
    var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    navEvt.setParams({
      "recordId": selectedRows[0].ID,
    });
    navEvt.fire();
}
```

Comment: The problem with using onrowselection is that you can click on more than one at time if you wanted to add more actions on the list of records.