# lightning dynamic component datatable onclick/onrowselection

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dynamic, datatable, onclick

I have a lightning component that dynamically creates a lightning:datatable when apex returns a list of records.
For the most part its working, but im trying to add an onclick event to the row, but however I try it its failing.

```
$A.createComponent(
        "lightning:datatable",
        {
            "data":component.get("v.results"),
            "columns":component.get("v.mycolumns")
            //,"onclick": "{!c.onrowselection}"
            //,"onrowselection": "{!c.onrowselection}"

        },
        function(datatable){                
            if (component.isValid()) {
                var targetCmp = component.find('datatable');
                var body = targetCmp.get("v.body");
                body.push(datatable);
                targetCmp.set("v.body", body); 
            }
        }
    );
```

You can see the commented code, if i uncomment it the component will not be created.
If you have an idea please post a comment or answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the component documentation for the [Lightning:datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_datatable.htm) you might notice that onclick is not a supported attribute.

When creating lightning components, if you declare unsupported attributes, they will not be created.

Comment: not only `onclick` is not supported, also any other attempts to use actions is not working now, although it will in the future - see the answer to my [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193276/winter-18-lightningdatatable-problems)

Comment: Thanks. I read the question and answers there. Can you please see my comment on the answer there.

Comment: So if I go back to using document.createElement('tr').. its working fine. if I add an inline function. please see my code, the first addeventlistner works, however if i try replacing it with the controller function it will not work(The page does load correctly though, just no click functionality).
              
var tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
tableRow.addEventListener("click", function(){
 alert('Clicked!');
});

                  
var cmpRef = component.getReference("c.onrowselection");
tableRow.addEventListener("click", cmpRef);

Answer (score 1):

use `component.getReference` to call the controller method while creating component dynamically,and as @glls says onclick is not supported attribute

```
$A.createComponent(
        "lightning:datatable",
        {
            "data":component.get("v.results"),
            "columns":component.get("v.mycolumns")
            "onrowselection": component.getReference("c.onrowselection")

        },
        function(datatable){                
            if (component.isValid()) {
                var targetCmp = component.find('datatable');
                var body = targetCmp.get("v.body");
                body.push(datatable);
                targetCmp.set("v.body", body); 
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it but it wont work. I made sure to change "cmp " to "component". Any other ideas?

Comment: ya its "component".can you point out what error is showing?