# How to show name of custom object in lightning component datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a Engagement object with a custom field Account__c that has Name field. I want to show the name of the Account, but currently it shows the Id. How can I show the Account__c.Name rather than Id?

Apex Class Code:

```
public class EngagedAccountController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Engagement__c> getEngagedAccounts(Id oppId) {
        Volunteer_Opportunity__c opp = [Select Name, Support_Required__c FROM Volunteer_Opportunity__c WHERE id = :oppId];
        List<Engagement__c> engagedAccounts = [Select Name, Account__c FROM Engagement__c WHERE Volunteer_Opportunity__c = :opp.Id];
        return engagedAccounts;
    } 
}
```

Lightning Component Javascript:

```
({
    myAction : function(component, event, helper) {

        component.set("v.Columns", [
            {label:"Name", fieldName:"Name", type:"text"},
            {label:"Account", fieldName:"Account__c", type:"text"}
        ]);

        var action_get_engaged_accounts = component.get("c.getEngagedAccounts");
        action_get_engaged_accounts.setParams({
            oppId: component.get("v.recordId")
        });

        action_get_engaged_accounts.setCallback(this, function(data) {
            component.set("v.accounts", data.getReturnValue());
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action_get_engaged_accounts); 
    }
})
```

Lightning Component Component:

```
<aura:component controller="EngagedAccountController" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="opportunity" type="Volunteer_Opportunity__c" />
    <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Engagement__c" />
    <aura:attribute name="Columns" type="List" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.myAction}" />

    <force:recordData aura:id="accountRecord"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      targetFields="{!v.opportunity}"
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      />

    <lightning:card iconName="standard:entitlement" title="{! 'Accounts engaged in this opportunity'}">
        <lightning:datatable data="{!v.accounts}" keyField="id" columns="{! v.Columns }" hideCheckboxColumn="true"/> 
    </lightning:card>

</aura:component>
```

How it looks currently:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK the `fieldName` attribute of `lightning:dataTable` does not support dotted expressions that cross object boundaries such as `Account__r.Name`.

So the simplest fix is to add a formula field called "Account Name" of `Account__r.Name` to your `Engagement__c` object and query and reference that in the table.

**PS**

Or use [this technique](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/200761/parent-field-in-lightning-datatable#answer-200779).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193273/winter-18-lightningdatatable-does-not-get-values-from-a-parent-record) and will have the same answer:

**First** of all you need to query the fields that you want to display, so in your SOQL query you should add `Account__r.Name` if you want to get the account name:

```
List<Engagement__c> engagedAccounts = [Select Name, Account__c, Account__r.Name FROM Engagement__c WHERE Volunteer_Opportunity__c = :opp.Id];
```

**Second** - your client controller will get the account data as nested json object, and for the `lightning:datatable` to handle all the fields, you need to flatten them, meaning:

**json data from server (example):**

```
{ "Id": a05S00000028b6aIAA, "Name": "Test Contact", "Account__r": { "Name": "Account Name", "Id": "001S000000pdfgdgf"} }
```

**flattened json data (works for lightning:datatable)**

```
{ "Id": a05S00000028b6aIAA, "Name": "Test Contact", "Account__r.Name": "Account Name", "Account__r.Id": "001S000000pdfgdgf"}
```

to flatten I use a method taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098797/fastest-way-to-flatten-un-flatten-nested-json-objects):

```
flattenRecord :function(data) {
    var result = {};
    function recurse (cur, prop) {
        if (Object(cur) !== cur) {
            result[prop] = cur;
        } else if (Array.isArray(cur)) {
            for(var i=0, l=cur.length; i<l; i++)
                recurse(cur[i], prop + "[" + i + "]");
            if (l == 0)
                result[prop] = [];
        } else {
            var isEmpty = true;
            for (var p in cur) {
                isEmpty = false;
                recurse(cur[p], prop ? prop+"."+p : p);
            }
            if (isEmpty && prop)
                result[prop] = {};
        }
    }
    recurse(data, "");
    return result;
}
```

You can add it just after you get the data from you server:

```
myAction : function(component, event, helper) {

    component.set("v.Columns", [
        {label:"Name", fieldName:"Name", type:"text"},
        {label:"Account", fieldName:"Account__r.Name", type:"text"}
    ]);

    var action_get_engaged_accounts = component.get("c.getEngagedAccounts");
    action_get_engaged_accounts.setParams({
        oppId: component.get("v.recordId")
    });

    action_get_engaged_accounts.setCallback(this, function(data) {
        var state = data.getState();
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            var accounts = data.getReturnValue();
            accounts = helper.flattenRecord(accounts);
            component.set("v.accounts", accounts);
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action_get_engaged_accounts); 
}
```