# Parent record data is not displayed in LWC data table

Tags: lightning-web-components

Following is my code and contact's first and last name is not displayed:

**HTML:**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Datatable Example" icon-name="custom:custom63">

        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <template if:true={contact.data}>
                <lightning-datatable
                    key-field="Id"
                    record-id={recordId}
                    data={contact.data}
                    columns={columns}
                    onsave={handleSave}
                    draft-values={draftValues}>
                </lightning-datatable>
            </template>
            <template if:true={contact.error}>
                <!-- handle Apex error -->
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**JS:**

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
import getContactList from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController1.getContactList';
const COLS = [
    { label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status', editable: true },
    { label: 'First Name', fieldName: 'Contact.FirstName', editable: true },
    { label: 'Last Name', fieldName: 'contact.lastName', editable: true },
    { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email' }
];
export default class DatatableUpdateExample extends LightningElement {
    @track error;
    @track columns = COLS;
    @track draftValues = [];

    @api recordId;

    @api conWrapper = []; 

    @wire(getContactList, {pRecId: '$recordId'})
    contact;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class ContactController1 {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<campaignmember> getContactList(string pRecId) {
        return [select id, contactid, Status, contact.firstname, contact.lastname, Email from campaignmember where Campaignid =: pRecId];
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/200761/parent-field-in-lightning-datatable/200779#200779 I believe this would solve your issue? You'd remove the "." from your fieldname and essentially assign the parent value to that row to contain parent data in the code snippet provided

Comment: This would fix your issue...https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/293088/lwc-salesforce-get-parent-in-datatable-column