# Lightning:datatable - nested JSON data

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable

Is there any way to access a nested data when loading a lightning:datatable?

*.cmp*

```
<lightning:datatable aura:id="datatable" data="{!v.data}" columns="{!v.columns}" keyField="id"/>
```

*.cmp controller*
...

```
component.set("v.columns", [{
        "fieldName": "A1.B1",
        "label": "Column 1",
        "type": "text"
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "A1.B2",
        "label": "Column 2",
        "type": "text"
    }
]);
component.set("v.data", [{
    "Id": "a1J0R0000001HmIUAU",
    "A1": [{
        "B1": "Test1",
        "B2": "Test2"
    }]
}]);
```

How to display B1 or B2? 
I believe the best way is to manipulate v.data to return 
"A1.B1" : "Test1" and "A1.B2" : "Test2". The solution below works, but I'd like to access without having to change the JSON structure.

```
component.set("v.columns", [{
        "fieldName": "A1.B1",
        "label": "Column 1",
        "type": "text"
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "A1.B2",
        "label": "Column 2",
        "type": "text"
    }
]);
component.set("v.data", [{
    "Id": "a1J0R0000001HmIUAU",
    "A1.B1": "Test1",
    "A1.B2": "Test2"
}]);
```

I don't believe child elements are currently supported.
Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported in a standard way - have a look at my regarding this:

[Winter 18 <lightning:datatable> does not get values from a parent record](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193273/winter-18-lightningdatatable-does-not-get-values-from-a-parent-record)

And the workaround is to flatten the server side result:

(Method taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098797/fastest-way-to-flatten-un-flatten-nested-json-objects)

```
flatten :function(data) {
    var result = {};
    function recurse (cur, prop) {
        if (Object(cur) !== cur) {
            result[prop] = cur;
        } else if (Array.isArray(cur)) {
            for(var i=0, l=cur.length; i<l; i++)
                recurse(cur[i], prop + "[" + i + "]");
            if (l == 0)
                result[prop] = [];
        } else {
            var isEmpty = true;
            for (var p in cur) {
                isEmpty = false;
                recurse(cur[p], prop ? prop+"."+p : p);
            }
            if (isEmpty && prop)
                result[prop] = {};
        }
    }
    recurse(data, "");
    return result;
}
```