# Binding of parent data in lightning data table

Tags: lightning, data

I have seen [Winter 18 <lightning:datatable> does not get values from a parent record](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193273/winter-18-lightningdatatable-does-not-get-values-from-a-parent-record/193419)

I am creating the data table dynamically . Its working fine by parent record is not showing on data table . Can you please help me . Should I post my code here

Comment: Yes, please **[edit]** your question and include your code so we can better assist you.

Comment: Yes i observed that it comes null workaround create formula or wrapper class. Catch is if you manualy refresh again it appers let me know if it is same to you?